# What does the date in Notification of Google Play Console indicates?

Tags: android, google-play-console

When we upload new or updates of the app in Google Play Console, after it goes live then we get notification shown in below screenshot. Now there we can find the date where it says "... created on MMM DD, YYYY, H:MM ...". I'm not understanding what that date mean. I mean to say, as you can see in below screenshot, the first apk I have developed near 8:00 pm to 8:30 pm and uploaded it on Google Play Console around 9:00 pm but it says that its created on May 24, 2020, 3:40 PM. I am not understanding what date it actually shows. If we can say timezone has been different then it should show changed date and times in Activity Log of Google Play Console. Activity log shows correct date of publication as you can see in screenshot given below.

What does the date in Notification panel mean? Is it a bug? If not, then what that date indicates?

**Notification Panel**

[image: Notification Panel of Google Play Console]

**Activity Log**

[image: Activity Log of Goolge Play Console]

Comment: timezone is GMT. Difference is between GMT and your local timezone.

Comment: and why they used GMT time in notification?